# A noun that means "something that is notable or noteworthy"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that means "something that is notable or noteworthy".  It seems like the word "notable" itself should suffice, but according to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/notable?s=t), the noun form of the word obsolete:

> 6. Obsolete. a notable fact or thing.

Given that there doesn't seem to be a great replacement, I'm wondering why the word (i.e. the noun form) would ever have become obsolete.  Is there another word I can use instead?

Comment: Only that particular use (definition 6) has become obsolete, not the word "notable" itself

Comment: A standout ????

Comment: Or something that is *green*. Or *angry*. Or *soft*. Or any number of other adjectives...

Comment: @roryap ah - I read your question wrong, sorry.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @MaxWilliams -- Thanks, I edited the question anyway to make it clearer that I'm referring to the noun form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, my definition search failed.  But the word I would use to represent things I thought were notable, or worthy of recognition is

**icon**

"The Apple IIe is an *icon* of innovation in the computer age."

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***notabilia***, defined [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/notabilia) as "matters, events, or items worthy of note."

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be more with insisting that the concept of importance be inherent in the noun rather than in an adjective applied to a noun. I think you are right, that there is no good replacement, though Silenius offers a functional one. We use more specific terms in certain contexts (***soul, essence, key, core, center, keystone***, etc.), but I think one could argue that we are clearest in our communication when we use an adjective to denote why a particular noun is notable or noteworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***phenomenon***.

ODO:

> **[phenomenon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/phenomenon)** *NOUN*
>
> **2A** remarkable person, thing, or event.
>
> ‘The exhibition pays tribute to Godzilla as cultural phenomenon rather than mere pop icon.’
>
> ‘One of the most remarkable economic phenomena over the past few years has been the emergence of Internet business.’
>
> **Synonyms**: marvel, sensation, wonder, prodigy, miracle, rarity,
> nonpareil, curiosity, spectacle